# ASP.NET/SQL Not retrieving correct value from database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

So I'm trying to create a monopoly web game using asp.net. I was having issues with variables being saved due to the postback, so I've created a database which stores all the info about the players and squares etc. The problem I'm having now however is for some reason the current player ID isn't being stored/retrieved correctly. I apologise for the relatively long wall of code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Monopoly_Web
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
        List<Square> squares = new List<Square>();
        Player currentPlayer;
        Square CurrentSquare;
        SQLDatabase.DatabaseTable players_table = new SQLDatabase.DatabaseTable("PlayersTable");
        SQLDatabase.DatabaseTable squares_table = new SQLDatabase.DatabaseTable("SquaresTable");
        SQLDatabase.DatabaseTable gameinfo_table = new SQLDatabase.DatabaseTable("GameInfoTable");
        int currentPlayerID = 0;
        int currentSquareID = 0;
        int freeParkingAmount = 500;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                readFromDatabase();
            }
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // MAIN GAME BUTTONS
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        protected void RollDiceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int dice = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(1, 7);   // Pick a number from 1 to 6 and add it to the current position.

            diceRoll.Visible = true;
            diceRoll.Text = "You rolled a " + dice.ToString();

            currentPlayer.SetPosition(MovePlayer(dice));
            CurrentSquare = squares[currentPlayer.GetPosition()];

            updateDisplay();
            RollDiceButton.Enabled = false;
            EndTurnButton.Enabled = true;
            writeToDatabase();
        }

        protected void BuyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            writeToDatabase();
        }

        protected void EndTurnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            diceRoll.Visible = false;
            buyLabel.Visible = false;
            payLabel.Visible = false;
            RollDiceButton.Enabled = true;
            BuyButton.Enabled = false;
            EndTurnButton.Enabled = false;
            //checkBankruptcy();
            changeActivePlayer();
            currentPlayerLabel.Text = "Current Player: " + currentPlayerID.ToString();
            updateDisplay();
            writeToDatabase();

        }

        protected void ResumeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resumeGame();
            RollDiceButton.Enabled = true;
            EndTurnButton.Enabled = true;
            StartButton.Visible = false;
            ResumeButton.Visible = false;
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // PLAYER MOVEMENT
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private int MovePlayer(int dice_value)
        {
            currentPlayer.SetPosition(currentPlayer.GetPosition() + dice_value);

            if (currentPlayer.GetPosition() > (squares.Count - 1))
            {
                currentPlayer.SetPosition(currentPlayer.GetPosition() % squares.Count());
                currentPlayer.SetMoney(200);
            }

            return currentPlayer.GetPosition();
        }

        private void changeActivePlayer()
        {
            currentPlayerID += 1;

            do
            {
                if (currentPlayerID >= players.Count())
                {
                    currentPlayerID = 0;
                }
                currentPlayer = players[currentPlayerID];
            } while (currentPlayer.IsBankrupt() == true);
        }


        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // START/RESUME GAME
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private void startGame()
        {
            createArrays();
            currentPlayer = players[0];
            CurrentSquare = squares[0];

            if (players_table == null)
            {
                foreach (Player player in players)
                {
                    SQLDatabase.DatabaseRow new_row = players_table.NewRow();
                    string new_id = players_table.GetNextID().ToString();

                    new_row["ID"] = new_id;
                    new_row["position"] = player.GetPosition().ToString();
                    new_row["money"] = player.GetMoney().ToString();
                    new_row["isInJail"] = player.IsInJail().ToString();
                    new_row["isBankrupt"] = player.IsBankrupt().ToString();

                    players_table.Insert(new_row);
                }
            }

            if (gameinfo_table == null)
            {
                SQLDatabase.DatabaseRow new_row = gameinfo_table.NewRow();

                new_row["ID"] = 1.ToString();
                new_row["CurrentPlayerID"] = currentPlayer.GetID().ToString();
                new_row["CurrentSquareID"] = CurrentSquare.GetID().ToString();
                new_row["FreeParkingAmount"] = freeParkingAmount.ToString();

                gameinfo_table.Insert(new_row);
            }
            writeToDatabase();
        }

        protected void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startGame();
            updateDisplay();
            RollDiceButton.Enabled = true;
            EndTurnButton.Enabled = true;
            StartButton.Visible = false;
            ResumeButton.Visible = false;
        }

        private void resumeGame()
        {
            readFromDatabase();
            updateDisplay();
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // READ/WRITE TO DATABASE
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private void readFromDatabase()
        {
            createArrays();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                //players[i].SetID(Convert.ToInt32(players_table.GetRow(i)["ID"]));
                players[i].SetPosition(Convert.ToInt32(players_table.GetRow(i)["position"]));
                players[i].SetMoney(Convert.ToInt32(players_table.GetRow(i)["money"]));
                players[i].SetInJail(Convert.ToBoolean(players_table.GetRow(i)["isInJail"]));
                players[i].SetIsBankrupt(Convert.ToBoolean(players_table.GetRow(i)["isBankrupt"]));
            }

            currentPlayerID = Convert.ToInt32(gameinfo_table.GetRow(0)["CurrentPlayerID"]);
            currentSquareID = Convert.ToInt32(gameinfo_table.GetRow(0)["CurrentSquareID"]);
            freeParkingAmount = Convert.ToInt32(gameinfo_table.GetRow(0)["FreeParkingAmount"]);

            currentPlayer = players[currentPlayerID];
            CurrentSquare = squares[currentSquareID];
        }

        private void writeToDatabase()
        {        
            foreach (Player player in players)
            {
                SQLDatabase.DatabaseRow prow = players_table.GetRow(player.GetID());

                //prow["ID"] = player.GetID().ToString();
                prow["position"] = player.GetPosition().ToString();
                prow["money"] = player.GetMoney().ToString();
                prow["isInJail"] = player.IsInJail().ToString();
                prow["isBankrupt"] = player.IsBankrupt().ToString();

                players_table.Update(prow);
            }

            SQLDatabase.DatabaseRow girow = gameinfo_table.GetRow(0);

            girow["CurrentPlayerID"] = currentPlayerID.ToString();
            girow["CurrentSquareID"] = CurrentSquare.GetID().ToString();
            girow["FreeParkingAmount"] = freeParkingAmount.ToString();
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // CREATE PLAYER AND SQUARE ARRAYS
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private void createArrays()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Player player = new Player(i);
                players.Add(player);
            }

            Square square0 = new Square(0, 0, 0, "Go", "go");
            Square square1 = new Square(1, 60, 2, "Old Kent Road", "prop");
            Square square2 = new Square(2, 0, 0, "Community Chest", "comm");
            Square square3 = new Square(3, 60, 4, "Whitechapel Road", "prop");
            Square square4 = new Square(4, 200, 0, "Income Tax", "tax");
            Square square5 = new Square(5, 200, 25, "Kings Cross Station", "prop");
            Square square6 = new Square(6, 100, 6, "The Angel Islington", "prop");
            Square square7 = new Square(7, 0, 0, "Chance", "chance");
            Square square8 = new Square(8, 100, 6, "Euston Road", "prop");
            Square square9 = new Square(9, 120, 8, "Pentonville Road", "prop");
            Square square10 = new Square(10, 0, 0, "Visiting Jail", "other");
            Square square11 = new Square(11, 140, 10, "Pall Mall", "prop");
            Square square12 = new Square(12, 150, 12, "Electric Company", "prop");
            Square square13 = new Square(13, 140, 10, "Whitehall", "prop");
            Square square14 = new Square(14, 160, 12, "Northumberland Avenue", "prop");
            Square square15 = new Square(15, 200, 25, "Marylebone Station", "prop");
            Square square16 = new Square(16, 180, 14, "Bow Street", "prop");
            Square square17 = new Square(17, 0, 0, "Community Chest", "comm");
            Square square18 = new Square(18, 180, 14, "Marlborough Street", "prop");
            Square square19 = new Square(19, 200, 16, "Vine Street", "prop");
            Square square20 = new Square(20, 0, 0, "Free Parking", "freep");
            Square square21 = new Square(21, 220, 18, "Strand", "prop");
            Square square22 = new Square(22, 0, 0, "Chance", "chance");
            Square square23 = new Square(23, 220, 18, "Fleet Street", "prop");
            Square square24 = new Square(24, 240, 20, "Trafalgar Square", "prop");
            Square square25 = new Square(25, 200, 25, "Fenchurch Street Station", "prop");
            Square square26 = new Square(26, 260, 22, "Leicester Square", "prop");
            Square square27 = new Square(27, 260, 22, "Coventry Street", "prop");
            Square square28 = new Square(28, 150, 12, "Water Works", "prop");
            Square square29 = new Square(29, 280, 22, "Piccadilly", "prop");
            Square square30 = new Square(30, 0, 0, "Jail", "jail");
            Square square31 = new Square(31, 300, 26, "Regent Street", "prop");
            Square square32 = new Square(32, 300, 26, "Oxford Street", "prop");
            Square square33 = new Square(33, 0, 0, "Community Chest", "comm");
            Square square34 = new Square(34, 320, 28, "Bond Street", "prop");
            Square square35 = new Square(35, 200, 25, "Liverpool Street Station", "prop");
            Square square36 = new Square(36, 0, 0, "Chance", "chance");
            Square square37 = new Square(37, 350, 35, "Park Lane", "prop");
            Square square38 = new Square(38, 100, 0, "Super Tax", "tax");
            Square square39 = new Square(39, 400, 50, "Mayfair", "prop");

            squares.Add(square0);
            squares.Add(square1);
            squares.Add(square2);
            squares.Add(square3);
            squares.Add(square4);
            squares.Add(square5);
            squares.Add(square6);
            squares.Add(square7);
            squares.Add(square8);
            squares.Add(square9);
            squares.Add(square10);
            squares.Add(square11);
            squares.Add(square12);
            squares.Add(square13);
            squares.Add(square14);
            squares.Add(square15);
            squares.Add(square16);
            squares.Add(square17);
            squares.Add(square18);
            squares.Add(square19);
            squares.Add(square20);
            squares.Add(square21);
            squares.Add(square22);
            squares.Add(square23);
            squares.Add(square24);
            squares.Add(square25);
            squares.Add(square26);
            squares.Add(square27);
            squares.Add(square28);
            squares.Add(square29);
            squares.Add(square30);
            squares.Add(square31);
            squares.Add(square32);
            squares.Add(square33);
            squares.Add(square34);
            squares.Add(square35);
            squares.Add(square36);
            squares.Add(square37);
            squares.Add(square38);
            squares.Add(square39);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know the database code I've got works fine as I can resume a game and it will set the player position to be the square they were at before. But for some reason when starting the game it is constantly player 2's turn, and the changeActivePlayer() doesn't seem do anything to help this. I stepped through the code line by line and after clicking the EndTurnButton the playerID had changed but when it came to getting the values from the database it was back to player 2's ID. I'm also not sure why it defaults to player 2, seeing as when I call the start game function I set the current player to players[0] so surely it should be player 1? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: In the _writeToDatabase_ it seems that you don't save the _girow_ data.

Comment: Thank you I knew it would be something simple I missed. Although it still doesn't want to start on player 1 but I'll hopefully find whats causing that